# firebase hosting url rewrite pattern matching

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

How do I rewrite urls like:

`http://somedomain.com/page.html`

to

`http://somedomain.com/DIRECTORY/page.html`

in firebase hosting. I tried this in `firebase.json` but didn't work.

```
  "rewrites": [ {
      "source": "/**.html",
      "destination": "/DIRECTORY/**.html"
    } ]
```

How does pattern matching work in firebase hosting config. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Firebase Hosting documentation on rewrites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites):

> The rewrites attribute contains an array of rewrite rules, where each rule must include:
>
> - A `source` specifying a [glob pattern](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#glob_pattern_matching)
> - A `destination`, which is a local file that must exist

So it looks like you can only rewrite to a specific, existing file, not to another wildcard.

You could consider using redirects instead, since those *do* support [dynamic segments in their destination URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#capture_url_segments_for_redirects).

```
"redirects": [ {
  "source": "/:page*",
  "destination": "http://somedomain.com/DIRECTORY/:page",
  "type": 301
}]
```

This sends a redirect instruction back to the client, so they will be able to see what the final path is.

Comment: I had seen it earlier but couldn't exactly figure out how it would work in my case. I gave it a try and came up with the config posted in my question which isn't working. Can you post the pattern for my problem (in question)?

Comment: Oh! I got it now.